# What is easy way to modify bit at given position using bit-wise operand?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have 3 variables which contain 8bit boolean data.

```
wAsIs =     0b11001100     //  <-- current data
wModified = 0b00001111 //  <-- given position
wInput =    0b10101010    //  <-- input data
```

I want to change each bit of `wAsIs` to `wInput` at `wModified` position. Expected result is:

```
1100 1010
```

What operations achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I have an idea: use [bit arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bitwise_operators). What did you try? What did you get?

Comment: I know bit arithmetic. I want to know is how to use that...

Comment: Why have you tagged C, C++, and C#? Which one are you asking about?

Comment: c, c++ and c# has bit-wise operand(& | << >> ~), so I don't care...

Answer (score 3):

First clear the relevant bits in the destination:

```
wAsIs & ~wModified
```

Extract the relevent bits in the source:

```
wInput & wModified
```

And set them in the destination:

```
wAsIs = (wAsIs & ~wModified) | (wInput & wModified);
```